# Can a linear map in $R^4$ be a subspace in $R_4[x]$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I would like to receive some help about the next problem:

Problem:

Let $U$ and $V$ be the subspaces of the vectorspace $\Bbb{R}_4[x]$. $U$ and $V$ are defined in the folowing way:

- $U = \mathcal{L}\left\{ (1, 3, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 0), (-1, 12, -5, 4) \right\}$
- $V$ is the set of all solutions of the next system of equations:
  $$ x - 2y + z + kt = 0,$$
  $$ 2x - 3y + z + 4t = 0,$$
  $$ 3x - 4y + 5t = 0.$$

Find such $k \in \Bbb{R}$ that $dim(V) = 1$ and for that $k$ find one base for $U$, $V$, $U \cap V$ and $U + V$.

Question:

Because, $(1, x, x^2, x^3)$ is the base of the $\Bbb{R}_4[x]$, how can $U$ be a subspace in $\Bbb{R}_4[x]$? One is set of ordered 4-tuples of real numbers and the other is set of polynomials.

Please, could someone explain to me where am i going wrong at understandnig this problem?

Comment: You are right. A tuple such as $(1,3,0,1)$ is not *per se* an element of $\Bbb R_4[x]$, simply because it is not a polynomial. We can only *assume* that the author *intended* this tuple to stand for $1+3x+0x^2+x^3$ (or perhaps for $x^3+3x^2+0x+1$)

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

The problem makes no sense. You are right: $U$ is *not* a subspace of $\mathbb{R}_4[x]$. By the way, neither is $V$. However, $U$ and $V$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^4$ and therefore you can still solve the problem.

There is a misunderstanding in your question, when you write that $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ is the basis of $\mathbb{R}_4[x]$. Do you really believe that tha space only has one basis? Besides, it is not even a basis. I suppose that you had $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4\}$ in mind.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I forgot to write that it's the standard base (that's how we call in my school). There was a bit of a misunderstanding considering some notations. In my school we use the next definition $\Bbb{R}_n[x] = \left\{ p \in \Bbb{R}[x] : deg(p) < n \right\}$. I don't know why.  I never asked. :)

Comment: @OgnjenMojovic I'm quite sure that that's not a standard notation. It has an advantage, though: with that definition, $\dim\mathbb{R}_n[x]=n$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: I believe the OP belongs to a language class that has no (definite or indefinite) articles (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_(grammar)#Variation_among_languages)). I know this from reading a translation of a book in russian from Landau-Lifshitz where analoguous situations where frequent (in the style "Let $A$ be the subspace of "B"").